# Power BI: Importing a huge dataset from MongoDB SQL Connector

Tags: mongodb, powerbi, powerquery, sqlconnection, data-import

I am getting this error while importing a dataset approximately 1.5 million rows from mongodb to powerbi through sql connector. I have used the same connection of other tasks, so the connection is good. I have filtered the rows to approximately 25000 rows. However, when I import my data into Power BI, I get this error:

**Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: [Expression.Error] Data source error occurred. SQLSTATE: 22003 NativeError: 0 Error message: ODBC: ERROR [22003] [MongoDB][API] integral data "3741325568" was truncated due to overflow. '.**

Furthermore, while loading into power bi or even further data processing. The power query seems to query on the whole dataset even after row filter.

Can anyone help?

Comment: are you sending a filter parameter when querying the database, or are you filtering it after retrieving the data?

Comment: I am filtering it after receiving it. I cant see any option to filter it before

Comment: for starters, you should [use views](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/views/) rather than importing whole tables. [here is an example of how you send parameters](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/How-do-I-pass-parameters-to-my-SQL-statement/m-p/118716) in power query - you can actually send whole SQL statements and use parameters.

Comment: advanced options in power query lets you include a SQL statement when tapping into a SQL database.

Comment: I do not see any advanced options for MongoDB Atlas SQL (Beta).

Comment: let
    Filter = "abc",
    Source = MongoDBAtlasODBC.Contents("", "database", []),
    Database = Source{[Name="database", Kind="Database"]}[Data],
    Table1_Table = Database{[Name="Table1",Kind="Table"]}[Data]
in
    Table1_Table       . This is the M query I have, lets just say that I want "topic" (a text column in Table1_Table) be exactly to be Filter text. Can you help me out? SQL statements do not seem to work for me in this case

Comment: An alternative way I found was to use python scripting and use pymongo library to fetch and filter data from the source. I think that this might give me issues during auto refresh for an embedded report but I am not at that stage yet.